# Avoid deletion of records in join table by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am a long time user of Hibernate, but I have a problem on one of my projects that I don't understand and, therefore, that I can't solve.

I have three tables linked through a join table.

Table 1 :

```
create table INPUTVALUERULE
(
    ID          BIGINT      not null constraint PK_INPUTVALUERULE primary key,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(30) not null,
    MANDATORY   SMALLINT,
    EDITABLE    SMALLINT
);
```

Table 2 :

```
create table ARTICLERULE
(
    ID         BIGINT not null constraint PK_ARTICLERULE primary key,
    STARTDATE  DATE   not null,
    ENDDATE    DATE,
    FK_ARTICLE BIGINT not null references ARTICLE
);
```

Table 3 :

```
create table INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT
(
    ID                       BIGINT generated always as identity constraint PK_INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT primary key,
    AMOUNTCONSTRAINT         VARCHAR(10) not null,
    REGULATORYNUMERICALVALUE DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

Join table :

```
create table INPUTVALUERULEARTICLERULEAMOUNTCONSTRAINT
(
    ID                       BIGINT generated always as identity primary key,
    FK_ARTICLERULE           BIGINT not null references ARTICLERULE,
    FK_INPUTVALUERULE        BIGINT not null references INPUTVALUERULE,
    FK_INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT BIGINT references INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT
);
```

The JPA relations are done in the entity classes.
In InputValueRule class, link to InputAmountConstraint :

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="INPUTVALUERULEARTICLERULEAMOUNTCONSTRAINT",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="FK_InputValueRule"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="FK_InputAmountConstraint")
    )
    private Set<InputAmountConstraint> articleAmountConstraints;
```

In ArticleRule class, link to InputValueRule :

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "InputValueRuleArticleRuleAmountConstraint",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ArticleRule"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_InputValueRule")
    )
    private Set<InputValueRule> inputValueRules = new HashSet<>();
```

No link in InputAmountConstraint class.

At the very first start of the application, liquibase will populate the join table INPUTVALUERULEARTICLERULEAMOUNTCONSTRAINT with 22 records :

| ID | FK_ARTICLERULE | FK_INPUTVALUERULE | FK_INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 | 3 | 729 | 75 |
| 74 | 3 | 497 | 75 |
| 53 | 12 | 497 | 75 |
| 54 | 12 | 498 | 20 |
| 55 | 15 | 498 | 17 |
| 56 | 43 | 497 | 75 |
| 57 | 46 | 497 | 75 |
| 58 | 47 | 497 | 75 |
| 59 | 48 | 497 | 75v |
| 60 | 50 | 497 | 7 |
| 61 | 51 | 497 | 20 |
| 62 | 52 | 497 | 20 |
| 63 | 53 | 497 | 20 |
| 64 | 55 | 497 | 20 |
| 65 | 58 | 497 | 20 |
| 66 | 51 | 598 | 20 |
| 67 | 52 | 598 | 20 |
| 68 | 53 | 598 | 20 |
| 69 | 55 | 598 | 20 |
| 70 | 58 | 598 | 20 |
| 71 | 2 | 729 | 75 |
| 72 | 2 | 497 | 75 |

But when I start to use the application, hibernate decide to "clean" the join table and only 12 records stay, of which only 7 are from the original 22 (the other 5 are inserted by hibernate with a null value in the FK_INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT column) :

| ID | FK_ARTICLERULE | FK_INPUTVALUERULE | FK_INPUTAMOUNTCONSTRAINT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 | 3 | 729 | 75 |
| 102 | 53 | 497 | null |
| 103 | 55 | 497 | null |
| 104 | 58 | 497 | null |
| 100 | 51 | 497 | null |
| 66 | 51 | 598 | 20 |
| 67 | 52 | 598 | 20 |
| 68 | 53 | 598 | 20 |
| 69 | 55 | 598 | 20 |
| 70 | 58 | 598 | 20 |
| 71 | 2 | 729 | 75 |
| 101 | 52 | 497 | null |

The problem is that, of course, I need the original 22 records for my application to work correctly.

I debugged a lot, tried a lot of possible solutions, but nothing solved my problem.

Regarding that, I have no idea why hibernate clean my join table (no orphanRemoval, no CASCADE.REMOVE,...) and how to avoid that.

Comment: Please provide your 22 records of liquibase migration for INPUTVALUERULEARTICLERULEAMOUNTCONSTRAINT.

Comment: Added in the question